# Find a four digit number $mcdu$ ,such that $m+c+d+u=(c-d)^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a  four digit number $mcdu$, such that $m+c+d+u=(c-d)^3$

None of the digits are 0.

I tried algebraic method, no success.

Comment: By $mcdu$ do you the concatenation of four digits? If so, have you thought about the maximum possible value of the LHS and how many perfect cubes are among those possibilities?

Comment: There seems to be several such numbers.  Do we need them all or just one? If the latter, which one?  Are thete other constraints?

Comment: Another thing that becomes important in solving this: is $0567$ considered a four digit number? (no that does not fulfil the equation, I thought that I wouldn't give a solution away)

Comment: What algebraic method?

Comment: Now that you've said none of the digits are $0$, I can say that the "solution" I wouldn't give away was $0100$. The method I hinted at in my first comment, and that ajotatxe also hint at in his answer, makes it possible to enumerate the 20 solutions (there would be two more if you allowed $u$ to be $0$, 4 if you also allowed $d$ to be $0$) and is what I would call algebraic.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Having in mind that the LHS is the sum of *four digits*, what are the possible values of $(c-d)^3$?

Comment: I count 20 solutions.

Comment: I also count 20 solutions, if the restriction that none of the digits are relaxed to just rule out leading zeroes, 4 more solutions can be found: $6200$, $5201$, $4310$ and $2420$.

Comment: @Henrik With zeros allowed, why not for example $1205$?

Comment: @aschepler: You're right, must have been because I started with $0$ as the final digit. When I then try to list the possibilities with $d=0$ I went to the beginning of my list (because that matched the lists I have with the assumptions in the question) and when I then reached $4310$ in my list, I must have thought there was no point in continuing lowering the first digit. (There's a hint in there). I also missed $4202$, $3203$ and $2204$.